# React state not updating inside custom route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am having an issue where my react state is not updating.
I am trying to make a role-based protected route, following this tutorial style https://dev.to/iamandrewluca/private-route-in-react-router-v6-lg5, using the following component:

```
const MasterRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const checkAuth = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let response = await getRole();
    setRole(response.role);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(role);
  }, [role])

  return role === 'ADMIN' ? children : <Navigate to="/" />;
}
```

Logging the `role` in the `useEffect` function displays an empty result in the console.
Logging the variable response directly after the await function displays the correct response retrieved from the server.

I've tried to console log the `role` directly after the `checkAuth()` function in `useEffect()`, but also obtained an empty line in the console.

What could be the problem?

This component is used as the following in App.js file:

```
<Route
  element={
    <MasterRoute>
      <Dashboard child={<Admin />}></Dashboard>
    </MasterRoute>
  }
  path={'/roles'}
></Route>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

It seems the general problem is that the initial `role` state is `''`, and since `'' === 'ADMIN'` evaluates `false` the `<Navigate to="/" />` is rendered  and the route changes. In other words, the route changed and `MasterRoute` likely isn't being rendered when the `checkAuth` call completes.

## Solution

You could use that `isLoading` state to conditionally render `null` or some loading indicator while the auth/role status us checked. You'll want `MasterRoute` to mount with `isLoading` initially `true` so no routing/navigation action is taken on the initial render cycle.

Example:

```
const MasterRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const [role, setRole] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // <-- initially true

  const checkAuth = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    let response = await getRole();
    setRole(response.role);
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(role);
  }, [role]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // or loading indicator/spinner/etc
  }

  return role === 'ADMIN' ? children : <Navigate to="/" replace />;
}
```